# Tensor product $a \otimes 0 = 0 = 0 \otimes b$, how are the elements in $N$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, tensor-products

I'm trying to solve $\text{Exercise } 9.19$ from Rotman's Algebraic Topology at the bottom of the below image, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  To show $a \otimes 0 = 0 = 0 \otimes b$, this would mean to show that $(a,0) + N = (0,0) + N = (0, b) + N$, or that $(a,0)$ and $(0, b)$ is in $N$ but I'm not sure how to show that either are in $N=\langle \{(a + a', b)-(a,b)-(a',b), (a, b+b') - (a,b) - (a, b')\} \rangle$.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you prove $0\otimes0\in N$?

Comment: $0 \otimes 0 = (0, 0) + N$.  and for something to be in $N$ it has to be of the form $m((a + a', b) - (a,b) - (a', b)) + n ((a,b + b') - (a,b) - (a,b'))$ for some $a,a', b, b', m,n$ in $A,B, \Bbb Z$. $(0 + 0, 0) - (0, 0) - (0,0)=(0,0) \in N$ for $a=a'=b=b'=\text{ id }$ and therefore $0 \otimes 0 \in N$.

Comment: Right, now prove that $0\otimes b\in N$.

Comment: Let $m=-1, a=a, a'=0, b=b$, we have:  $-1 ((a+0, b) - (a,b) - (0,b)) = -1(-(0,b)) = (0,b)$.

Comment: It would be best to provide the author and title for the text you are citing, in order to give proper attribution.

Answer (score 4):

Note that, by the definition of tensor product, we have
$$a\otimes 0 = a\otimes (0+0) = a\otimes 0 + a\otimes 0$$
so subtracting gives $a\otimes 0 = 0$.